# Do I need coupling capacitors with this balun?

Tags: rf, balun

I'm connecting an antenna to Atmel's SAMR21 microcontroller and [the datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-42223-sam-r21_datasheet.pdf) provides this guidance:

[image: an impedance matching framework]

I've found [2450BL15B100E](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/87146.pdf), an SMD balun, but I'm not sure if it actually contains a transformer, or if it's in fact a lumped LC balun (in which case I'm guessing I wouldn't need the coupling capacitors?).

So, should I put the coupling capacitors between the processor and the aforementioned part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer will largely depend on the internal makeup of the input port of the microcontroller. A DC path to ground from the balanced RF input port is likely to be undesirable, especially if the manufacturer has suggested capacitive coupling. These lines could go directly to transistor stages and the DC grounding (through the balun winding centre-tap) would alter the biasing.

Is there a good reason not to include the coupling capacitors?

Comment: There is no reason other than I've already had PCBs made and soldered everything on. :)

Comment: Can you cut the tracks and fit a tiny cap over the cut?

Comment: I can't, the balun is right next to the MCU.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is, can you tell from the datasheet if the part has a DC path between the balanced ports? It wouldn't if it were a lumped balun, would it?

Comment: I mean between a port and the ground.

Comment: Okay, so the question now has expanded a little to include what might be the real world effects of leaving the capacitors off. Firstly, it is possible that there will be no effect. But if you are unlucky, this could change internal biasing. For an Rx port this could affect noise figure / receiver sensitivity, or for a Tx port this could affect spectral shape, max tx power, and efficiency (due to amplifiers operating in a different class to their intended operation). How important is your RF performance?

Comment: No actually, I understand it would be bad if there was a DC path from the MCU port to the ground. What I'm not sure is whether there is one or not, since there is not equivalent circuit provided in the datasheet and maybe it's a lumped balun and so there is a capacitor embedded in the part. Now, since I've already soldered it, there is a DC path, but it might as well be through the MCU.

Comment: it took me too long to write my last comment and you beat me to it with several more ;) If it were a balun made of discrete Ls and Cs, the way I did it in the past, then it would have a DC path to ground on one arm, but not the other. I can't find a design reference, but when I do I will post it.

Comment: I actually couldn't wait and though I didn't want to, I unsoldered the balun to measure it in isolation. The balanced ports and one of the grounds are all DC-connected. So are the unbalanced port and the other ground. The unbalanced and the balanced ports have no DC connection. This would be consistent with the part being a transformer, so I'll go with that. It also means that I definitely need the capacitors between the balun and the MCU. Thanks for the answer and the discussion!

Comment: Not the result you wanted but good to know one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Put the coupling caps in .Even if there is no DC upset without them they still have a role to play.What they do is attenuate the really low frequency stuff. There are lots of unwanted signals around in our crowded RF spectrum .The stronger ones tend to be at the lower end but not always.The coupling caps could make your RF link less likely to get crunched by unwanted interference.